# How to find out the number of instances of a servlet running in Tomcat?

Tags: java, servlet-3.0, tomcat8

I very well understand that a Servlet is by default multithreaded and there will be only one instance of it running in the container even when it is servicing multiple requests. However, the only exception to this rule is when the servlet implements `SingleThreadModel` interface.

My question is: 
How to find out the number of instances of a servlet running in a container such as Tomcat at a given point of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a private static int member variable and increment it when a servlet is created, decrement it when destroyed.

Comment: When would the destroy() method get called? When I close the browser ?

Comment: The servlet lifetime (create/destroy) is not guaranteed to match request lifetimes, e.g. the container might create one per request or might use a singleton. Singleton is actually the norm these days, so that won't work at all.

Comment: @user2325154 No, the servlets lifetime has nothing to do with the browser. The server is not notified when you close the browser or navigate away from the current page.

Comment: Ok, so does that mean that I can never see the variable getting decremented? I still wondering, when exactly would the destroy() method get called ?

Comment: The servlet `init` method is called when the webapp is started (at Tomcat startup and/or when deployed), and the `destroy` method is called when the webapp is stopped (at Tomcat shutdown and/or when undeployed/redeployed). The single servlet instance is then used by **all** incoming requests, so your counter is always `1`. Not useful at all.

Comment: @Andreas In general, you're probably correct. However, it is up to the servlet container to decide. From the Javadoc: "If a servlet implements this interface, you are guaranteed that no two threads will execute concurrently in the servlet's service method. The servlet container can make this guarantee by synchronizing access to a single instance of the servlet, or by maintaining a pool of servlet instances and dispatching each new request to a free servlet." Either way, the interface is deprecated so it's probably not a great idea to rely on it.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to Java EE applications monitoring, I always fire up `jconsole` tool which is shipped with JDK and see what information an Application Server exposes. For example, that's what you see when you connect to Tomcat, and select `Catalina -> Servlet -> Your servlet -> attributes` on MBeans tab:

[image]

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, since I haven't worked with STM Servlets before, but you can definitely find some useful information there.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static int activeRequests;

    public static int getActiveRequests() {
        return activeRequests;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        activeRequests++;
        try {
            // do your processing here
        } finally {
            activeRequests--;
        }
    }

}
```

For best concurrency, you can replace `int` with `AtomicInteger`, but that shouldn't be necessary for simple `++` and `--` of an `int`.